# CompilerServices for class name

Tags: c#

I've been using the CompilerServices library to get out the method name of the calling function for logging reasons.

What I was wondering though is it possible to get the calling class?
I've looked through all the attributes with no success.

Direct from [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx):

```
public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}
```

I really want to avoid the StackFrame heap.

Comment: No, not supported.  If you use a source file for every class then you don't care that it isn't supported.

Comment: You could always suggest it for future: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

Comment: thanks and done :) 
(http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2252418-caller-info-attribute-callermembernamespace-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  The `Caller`* attributes (at least currently) only provide the three items you listed, but not the type.

If you need to get the actual type, using the stack information is really the only way to get there.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no there is no way to do this.  The set of attributes you listed are the full set of features available with the caller information feature.  Here is a link to a detailed page that covers the options available.  Class name is not one of them.

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540.aspx